# Storing data from ajax error response to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to obtain a message value from my ajax error response.

within my python code, i'm sending this.

```
return JsonResponse({'message':'Online payment of this invoice not supported.'}, status=401)
```

Within the error section of my ajax response, if I console.log(error), I see the following response details.

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ ( statusText )
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )
overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type )
pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ ( obj )
readyState: 4
responseJSON: {message: "Please ensure that this invoice is eligible for payment."}
responseText: "{"message": "Please ensure that this invoice is eligible for payment."}"
setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value )
state: ƒ ()
status: 401
statusCode: ƒ ( map )
statusText: "Unauthorized"
success: ƒ ()
then: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
__proto__: Object
```

Within my javascript, how can I store my message from responseJSON to a variable? In other words, I want to store the following string in a variable: Please ensure that this invoice is eligible for payment.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using `fetch`?  or `jQuery.ajax`?  or some other javascript AJAX library?

Comment: jQuery.ajax is what i'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var responseJSON = error.responseJSON;
        var message = responseJSON['message'];
```